# Declare an attribute that both extends a class and implements an interface

Tags: java

I found this question: [Member variable which must extend class A and implement some interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582721/member-variable-which-must-extend-class-a-and-implement-some-interface)

and was wondering if there is a better way. Passing it as a parameter in a method works:

```
public <T extends Activity & IMyInterface> void start(T _callback) {
    callback = _callback;
}
```

but how to correctly declare `callback` as attribute? This:

```
Class<? extends Activity & IMyInterface> callback;
```

gives a syntax error.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<T extends Activity implements IMyInterface>`? You implement an interface, not extend it.

Comment: @ThaMe90 my thoughts as well, but according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641584/method-argument-extends-class-implements-interface this is how it's done.

Comment: Ha, I never knew that (I found the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) that goes along with that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that T is not an instance of Class, you can declare it as:

```
Object callback;
MyType callback;
MyInterface callback;
```

Or you can define your class to be generic like this:

```
public class Example<T extends MyType & MyInterface>{
   T callback
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare a variable that extends a class and implements an interface, you must declare the type variable on the class level, as based on this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4), you cannot declare the type variable on class attributes.

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyType & MyInterface>{
  T extendsBothMyTypeAndInterface;
}
```