# Type Variable with class and interface: inheritence problems

Tags: java

My project uses an external library which provides classes `A` and `B` (where `B extends A`). I want to add a few methods to `A`, but I want them to be in `B` too, so I have created an interface `Custom` and created the classes:

- `CustomA extends A implements Custom`
- `CustomB extends B implements Custom`

I now want to uses those 2 new classes **interchangeably** in class `C`, as both attributes and method arguments. I have found this question: [Declare an attribute that both extends a class and implements an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427902/declare-an-attribute-that-both-extends-a-class-and-implements-an-interface), so I have tried the following code:

```
public class C<T extends A & Custom>{
   private T attr1;
   private T attr2;
   public void createAttrs() {
       attr1 = new CustomA();
       attr2 = new CustomB();
   }
   public void setAttr1(T attr1) {
       this.attr1 = attr1;
   }
   public void setAttr2(T attr2) {
       this.attr2 = attr2;
   }
}
```

However this code did not compile because of "Incompatible types" in the `createAttrs()` method. But `CustomA` and `CustomB` both extend `A` (directly or indirectly) and implement `Custom`, so it matches the pattern of the Type Variable `T`.

How can I make this code work?

Edit: What I'm really looking for is a way to use `CustomA` and `CustomB` interchangeably, in the same fashion I could originally store both an `A` and a `B` object in a variable typed `A`.

Comment: Why not add methods in A and override in B ?

Comment: Why exactly are you using `T`?

Comment: @Frank, for example, because he doesn't control neither `A` nor `B`, but he controls `Custom`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither a `new CustomA()` nor a `new CustomB()` can't be used within the `createAttrs` since you're describing a template and at this time you don't know what the type `T` is gonna be.

It can be a `CustomA` or a `CustomB`, but it also can be any class that follows the rule `T extends A & Custom`.

It makes no sense to make a class generic and use a concrete implementation inside it. So I would suggest getting these attributes from method parameters:

```
class C<T extends A & Custom> {
    private T attr1;
    private T attr2;

    public void createAttrs(T attr1, T attr2) {
        this.attr1 = attr1;
        this.attr2 = attr2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C<>().createAttrs(new CustomA(), new CustomB());
    }
}
```

Comment: He's likely uses generics to work around the fact that Java doesn't have union types yet, where he could just say `A&Custom` in variable type.

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that I had a method `void doStuff(T attr)` that can take either a `CustomA` or a `CustomB` as an argument. And the same thing applies for my attributes, I don't know in advance if it will be a `CustomA` or `CustomB`

Comment: @BenoîtVernier, I missed out the fact that the `B` extends `A` - corrected the answer. What's the idea to make the class generic? Why wouldn't you go with the concrete `CustomA` and `CustomB` fields?

Answer (score 0):

What you say in `C` is that `attr1` and `attr2` must be of the same type `T` which extends `A`, implements `Custom` and both `CustomA` and `CustomB` are assignment-compatible to it.

No such type exists.